# Move right-aligned paragraph more to the center

Tags: horizontal-alignment, paragraphs

So I am typesetting a little songbook for our Christmas get-together. To make better use of the limited space, I am using the `multicol` package; no issues there.

What I'd like to do is move a whole paragraph horizontally an arbitrary amount of space. In the following MWE take a look at stanza #3. It uses a `\begin{flushright}` environment, but I'd still like to move it a bit more to the center, keeping the right edge neatly aligned.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=A5,DIV=14,headinclude=true,footinclude=true,headings=small,pagesize,parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,naustrian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true,protrusion=true,factor=900,draft=false]{microtype}

\usepackage{multicol, sectsty}

\raggedbottom
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{2.5cm}
\allsectionsfont{\large\centering}

\begin{document}
    \section{The Little Drummer Boy}
        \begin{multicols}{2}

            1. Come, they told me,\\ 
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            our new born King to see, \\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            our finest gifts we'll bring, \\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            to lay before the King, \\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            \emph{rum pum pum pum,\\ rum pum pum pum.}

            So to honor Him,\\ 
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            when we come.

        \columnbreak

            2. Little Baby, \\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            I am a poor boy, too,\\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            I have no gift to bring,\\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            that's fit to give a King,\\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            \emph{rum pum pum pum,\\ rum pum pum pum}

            Shall I play for you,\\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            on my drum? 

    \end{multicols}
    \begin{flushright}

            3. Mary nodded, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            the ox and lamb kept time, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            I played my drum for Him, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            I played my best for Him, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            rum pum pum pum, rum pum pum pum.

            Then He smiled at me, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            me and my drum.

    \end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply specify a different `\rightskip` inside the `flushright`.  `flushright` works by putting `\rightskip` to `0pt` and `\leftskip` to exandable glue.  Replace the `\rightskip` value by some positive length, e.g. by

```
\begin{flushright}%
  \setlength{\rightskip}{3em}%
  ...
\end{flushright}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=A5,DIV=14,headinclude=true,footinclude=true,headings=small,pagesize,parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,naustrian]{babel}

\usepackage{multicol, sectsty}

\raggedbottom
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{2.5cm}
\allsectionsfont{\large\centering}

\begin{document}
    \section{The Little Drummer Boy}
        \begin{multicols}{2}

            1. Come, they told me,\\ 
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            our new born King to see, \\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            our finest gifts we'll bring, \\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            to lay before the King, \\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            \emph{rum pum pum pum,\\ rum pum pum pum.}

            So to honor Him,\\ 
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            when we come.

        \columnbreak

            2. Little Baby, \\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            I am a poor boy, too,\\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            I have no gift to bring,\\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            that's fit to give a King,\\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            \emph{rum pum pum pum,\\ rum pum pum pum}

            Shall I play for you,\\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            on my drum? 

    \end{multicols}
    \begin{flushright}
      Ordinary flushright text.
    \end{flushright}
    \begin{flushright}%
      \setlength{\rightskip}{3em}%
            3. Mary nodded, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            the ox and lamb kept time, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            I played my drum for Him, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            I played my best for Him, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            rum pum pum pum, rum pum pum pum.

            Then He smiled at me, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            me and my drum.

    \end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

Comment: for a verse this is probably OK but it's worth noting that changing `\rightskip` directly is not generally safe in latex and will break any nested display structures as they will not know the effective line width. making a simple list environment (like `flushleft` or `quote` but modifying the setting of `\rightmargin` rather than `\rightskip` would ensure that `\@totalleftmargin` and `\linewidth` got updated as the margin changed.

Comment: Thank you, it's working beautifully. @David: Duly noted, but luckily that's not an issue in my little example.

Comment: @Ingmar I guessed not, but code on the forum lasts forever and gets copied who knows where:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What do you use to compile this document. I dont seem to have the `MinionPro.sty`

Comment: @azetina I didn't:-) but the main point of the question doesn't need the font packages, it would apply to cm just as much.

Comment: My mistake. You can safely take out the font-related packages. In fact I will modify the MWE.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for pointing this out. As I said I was taking my cue from the way `flushright` is defined via the `\raggedleft` command.  It turns out the appropriate list like environment you mention is actually defined by the KOMA classes via the `\addmargin` command, see cgneider's comment to azetina's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two examples where you don't need to specify an explicit length:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=A5,DIV=20,headinclude=true,footinclude=true,headings=small,pagesize,parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,naustrian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true,protrusion=true,factor=900,draft=false]{microtype}

\usepackage{multicol, sectsty}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\raggedbottom
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{2.5cm}
\allsectionsfont{\large\centering}

\begin{document}
    \section{The Little Drummer Boy}
        \begin{multicols}{2}

            1. Come, they told me,\\ 
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            our new born King to see, \\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            our finest gifts we'll bring, \\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            to lay before the King, \\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            \emph{rum pum pum pum,\\ rum pum pum pum.}

            So to honor Him,\\ 
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            when we come.

        \columnbreak

            2. Little Baby, \\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            I am a poor boy, too,\\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            I have no gift to bring,\\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            that's fit to give a King,\\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            \emph{rum pum pum pum,\\ rum pum pum pum}

            Shall I play for you,\\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            on my drum? 

    \end{multicols}

    \noindent
    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

    \begin{center}
      \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
        \begin{flushright}
          3. Mary nodded, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
          the ox and lamb kept time, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
          I played my drum for Him, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
          I played my best for Him, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
          rum pum pum pum, rum pum pum pum.

          Then He smiled at me, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
          me and my drum.
        \end{flushright}
      \end{varwidth}
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
        3. Mary nodded, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
        the ox and lamb kept time, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
        I played my drum for Him, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
        I played my best for Him, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
        rum pum pum pum, rum pum pum pum.\\
        Then He smiled at me, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
        me and my drum.
      \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another suggestion using the `changepage` package:

We make use of the `adjustwidth` environment that controls the left and right margin of the text in question:

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{0in}{1in} % Here 1in defines the extra tabbing you need. 
    \begin{flushright}
    3. Mary nodded, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
    the ox and lamb kept time, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
    I played my drum for Him, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
    I played my best for Him, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
    rum pum pum pum, rum pum pum pum.

    Then He smiled at me, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
    me and my drum.
   \end{flushright}
\end{adjustwidth}
```

[image]

For a MWE, see below:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=A5,DIV=14,headinclude=true,footinclude=true,headings=small,pagesize,parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,naustrian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true,protrusion=true,factor=900,draft=false]{microtype}
%\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage[oldstyle,semibold]{sourcesanspro}

\usepackage{multicol, sectsty}
\usepackage{changepage}

\raggedbottom
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{2.5cm}
\allsectionsfont{\large\centering}

\begin{document}
    \section{The Little Drummer Boy}
        \begin{multicols}{2}

            1. Come, they told me,\\ 
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            our new born King to see, \\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            our finest gifts we'll bring, \\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            to lay before the King, \\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            \emph{rum pum pum pum,\\ rum pum pum pum.}

            So to honor Him,\\ 
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            when we come.

        \columnbreak

            2. Little Baby, \\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            I am a poor boy, too,\\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            I have no gift to bring,\\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            that's fit to give a King,\\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            \emph{rum pum pum pum,\\ rum pum pum pum}

            Shall I play for you,\\
            \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            on my drum? 

    \end{multicols}
        \begin{adjustwidth}{0in}{1in} % Here 1in defines the extra tabbing you need. 
    \begin{flushright}
            3. Mary nodded, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            the ox and lamb kept time, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            I played my drum for Him, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            I played my best for Him, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            rum pum pum pum, rum pum pum pum.

            Then He smiled at me, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
            me and my drum.
    \end{flushright}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

You can also use a combination of `\hfill` and the `minipage` environment. See below:

```
\null\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
 \begin{flushright}
    3. Mary nodded, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
    the ox and lamb kept time, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
    I played my drum for Him, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
    I played my best for Him, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
    rum pum pum pum, rum pum pum pum.

    Then He smiled at me, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
    me and my drum.
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
\hfill\null
```

@cgnieder suggests using the `\begin{addmargin}[0in]{1in}...` like environment to achieve the desired result since a KOMA class is being used.

```
\begin{addmargin}[0in]{1in}
\begin{flushright}
   3. Mary nodded, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
      the ox and lamb kept time, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
      I played my drum for Him, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
      I played my best for Him, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
      rum pum pum pum, rum pum pum pum.

      Then He smiled at me, \emph{pa rum pum pum pum},\\
      me and my drum.
\end{flushright}
\end{addmargin}
```

Comment: Since a KOMA class is used I'd rather use KOMA-Script's `\begin{addmargin}[0in]{1in} ...` which should do the same